# Cartesian Self Join Finding Unique Pairs Python

Tags: python, pandas, join, unique

I have a dataframe where I want to do a cartesian join on one specific column. It looks like this:

```
Name
abc
abd
abe
```

And I used cartesian join from sklearn:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(cartesian((df['Name'], df['Name'])), columns= 
['Name1', 'Name2'])
df_new['Score'] = df_new.apply(lambda somefunc:)
df_new = df_new[df_new['Name1']!=df_new['Name2']
```

So I have all the combinations of Name1 and Name2 along with some calculations I did. Now I want to find a way to aggregate the pairs(order doesn't matter) and average the Score. I haven't found a way to easily do this. I've tried to zip the two Name columns and use list and set functions without any success.

The dataframe looks like this after the cartesian join:

```
Name1, Name2, Score
abc, abd, 90
abc, abe, 80
abc, abg, 85
abd, abc, 70
```

So I would like to aggregate it to become like this:

```
Name1, Name2, Score
abc, abd, 80
abc, abe, 80
abc, abg, 85
```

I thought about not using cartesian join, but I really need to see the score for the ordered pair and then aggregate to unique pair. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54737348/how-to-summarize-on-different-groupby-combinations `sort` the Name columns and re-assign them back, then you can groupy the sorted columns.

Comment: Got it thanks guys